# React JS reduce API calls in function

Tags: json, reactjs, api

As you can see, I am calling my API 3 times. Once in componentDidMount, twice in each functions. How do I reduce the number of API calls to only once, in componentDidMount(), to make the code more efficient?

This is a simple calling from an API that generates a list, and I am doing a **Category dropdown** and **Search field** that works with the list.

I imagined that something from the functions need to be moved elsewhere for it to work. Any idea?

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }

        this.ChangeCategory = this.ChangeCategory.bind(this);
        this.btnSearch = this.btnSearch.bind(this);
    }

componentDidMount(){
        fetch('https://examplejson.json')
            //use es6 arrow function to not lose context of 'this'
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    items: json.response,
                })

                var items = json.response;

                //Populate category into dropdownlist
                var select = document.getElementById("locality");
                var options = [];
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                var i = 0;

                var uniqueNames = [];
                for(i = 0; i< items.length; i++){
                    if(uniqueNames.indexOf(items[i].category) === -1){
                        uniqueNames.push(items[i].category);        
                    }        
                }

                for(i = 0; i< uniqueNames.length; i++){    
                    option.text = option.value = option.key = uniqueNames[i];
                    options.push(option.outerHTML);      
                }

                select.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', options.join('\n'));
                //Populate category into dropdownlist
            }).catch(console.log);
            
    }
```

My 2 functions

```
ChangeCategory(){
        fetch('https://examplejson.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            var category;
            var x;
  
            category = json.response;
    
            var result = category.filter((z)=>z.category === document.getElementById("locality").value);

            var items2 = [];
            for (x in result) {
                items2[x] = result[x];
            }

            this.setState({
                items: items2,
            })
            
        }).catch(console.log);

        document.getElementById("txtBox1").value = '';

    }

btnSearch(){    
        fetch('https://examplejson.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            var items;
            var y;
            var searchItem = [];

            items = json.response;
    
            //filter by channel name, search the list with keyword from textbox (don't need to be exact word)
            var result = items.filter((z)=>z.title.toUpperCase().indexOf(document.getElementById("txtBox1").value.toUpperCase()) !== -1);
            
            for (y in result) {
                searchItem[y] = result[y];
            }
    
            this.setState({
                items: searchItem,
            })
            
        }).catch(console.log);
    
        document.getElementById("locality").selectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Render

```
render() { 

        var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

        if(!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }

        else {
            return (

                
            <div className="list">
                <div className="row mb-5">

                    <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 category-wrap">
                        <select key="locality" id="locality" className="form-control" name="locality" onChange={this.ChangeCategory} style={{padding:"5px", width:"250px"}}>
                            <option>Select category</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 search-wrap">
                        <div className="input-group" style={{width:"250px"}}>
                            <input key="txtBox1" type="text" id="txtBox1" className="form-control" placeholder="Channel Name" onKeyPress={event => {
                                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                                this.btnSearch()
                                }
                            }}/>
                            <button id="btnClick1" className="btn" onClick={this.btnSearch}><i className="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://examplejson.json')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            // There could be some logic to modify items, like uniqueness
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: json.response, // Items used for filtering
                filteredItems: json.response, // Items to render
            })
        )}
}
```

Then, in functions btnSearch and ChangeCategory, you can use "this.state.items" instead of calling api and using response.

Also I do not recommend using document.getElementById (or document.createElement ...). Instead, use state.

```
<input
    value={this.state.text}
    onChange={(e) => setState({ text: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Rendering options like this:

```
<select name="locality" onChange={this.ChangeCategory} value={this.state.value}>
    {this.state.options.map((item) => {
        return <option key={item} value="select">{item}</option>
    })}
</select>
```

If you still need access to DOM elements, consider using "refs".

## EDIT:

https://codesandbox.io/s/testapp-nekot
This is what I meant

- see what does it mean controlled vs uncontrolled components
- how to render collection
- unless you need some magic in app, you should never use document.getElementById

Comment: Thanks for the response. But there are some issues here.

For the select input field, it gives me an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. And the error points to my `style={{padding:"5px", width:"250px"}}>`, where I pasted the `value={this.state.value}` right after it.

And for the text input field, I'm confused on how to incorporate or replace the `document.getElementById` with the state that you suggested.

Comment: @HaydenNg That was incomplete code, I thought that you would finish it. See the edited answer with codesandbox.